# C# parallel processing options

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, threadpool

I am trying to get a portion of my code running in parallel, I have attempted to use the ThreadPool in c# to avoid any headaches, however it seems that I am asking too much of the pool, my code actually runs slower with it!

The code below explains what I am trying to do, I have a number of audio samples (depending on buffer size anywhere from 512->4096) that need to be inserted, propagated through and read from nodes (anywhere from n = 4 to n = 16)  in a delay network. This HAS to happen on a sample by sample basis, so my only option for optimisation is to take the part that insets/propagates/reads and have parallel operations for each node present in the network. This operation is called once per gameplay frame and is needed for the lifetime of the game. Looking at a profiler the scattering operation takes a substantial amount of time so it is a good candidate for this (I have done traditional optimisation already). At the moment I have the threadpool worker doing the work for all nodes in one work item, just to get up and running but the work can be split up later.

I think the issue with the code below is the frequency of work items being inserted into the threadpool, I have also read somewhere that threads take a while to spin up so if threadpool creates more it does not neccserally help. Does anyone have any suggestions on other parallel processing methods or can spot any mistakes with my threadpool implementation?

```
public void propagateNetwork() {

    int numSampsToConsume = Mathf.min(inSamples.Count,buffersize);

    for (int i = 0; i < numSampsToConsume; i++) {
        outVal = 0.0f;
        inVal = inSamples.Dequeue () * networkInScale;

        directDelay.write (inVal);
        directVal = directDelay.read ();
        directVal *= directAtt;

        for (j = 0; j < network.Count; j++) {
            outVal += network [j].getOutgoing ();
            network [j].inputIncoming (inVal);
        }

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (scatteringThreadPoolWrapper);
        scatteringThreadDone.WaitOne ();

        outVal += directVal;
        outSamples.Enqueue (outVal);
    }
}

public void scatteringThreadPoolWrapper(object threadConext) {
    doScatteringForNodeRange (0, network.Count);
}

public void doScatteringForNodeRange(int min,int max) {
    for (int i = min; i < max; i++) {
        network[i].doScattering (doLateReflections);
    }
    scatteringThreadDone.Set ();
}
```

Comment: If you queue and then immediately wait, doesn't that remove the point of doing it? Shouldn't you queue all of the work items, then wait for them to complete in another loop? Perhaps consider replacing your outside for with `Parallel.for`?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding what the threadpool does, but I am assuming that each task I assign to it is likely to be on different threads. Therefore overall it will complete quicker? I know in the example code I am not splitting the work up yet, it was just a test to see if it works. I need to wait because each sample must finish propagation before moving onto the next, for this same reason a parallel for is not possible.

Comment: Each task may be on a different thread, but if you send a task to another thread and then wait to get the answer back on the main thread before running another task, then of course you are slower. You are still only running one thread at a time, but you have added the overhead of creating threads and cross-thread communication.

Comment: Sure that makes sense. Like I said, the implementation above is not the true parallel verison. I would ideally split the nodes to be processed, so send half to be processed by the threadpool and the remaining processed in the main thread - the wait is there to make sure everything is done before the next sample.

The overhead increase is pretty suprising to me, the serial version of the code in a profiler shows an average of 200ms to compute whereas the parallel is around 1000ms!

Comment: Did you try TPL Dataflow for this?

Comment: @VMAtm I had not heard of that before, unfortunately I am working with unity (therefore mono) which I beleive does not include TPL yet and therefore dataflow

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using `Parallel.for` will work? I made some variables local to each loop iteration, but I don't know what the operations are all doing, and how that may cause issues if run in parallel.

```
public void propagateNetwork() {
    int numSampsToConsume = Mathf.min(inSamples.Count,buffersize);

    Parallel.for(0, numSampsToConsume, i => {
        var outVal = 0.0f;
        var inVal = inSamples.Dequeue () * networkInScale;

        directDelay.write (inVal);
        var directVal = directDelay.read ();
        directVal *= directAtt;

        Parallel.for(0, network.Count, j => {
            outVal += network [j].getOutgoing ();
            network [j].inputIncoming (inVal);
        });

        doScatteringForNodeRange (0, network.Count);

        outVal += directVal;
        outSamples.Enqueue (outVal);
    });
}
```

Comment: Just implemented the innermost parallel for, and it still takes longer than a normal for loop! Would a parallel for be creating new threads for each i, unlike threadpool which attempts to reuse as many in the pool and only create when needed? I think my main issue is that spinning up new threads takes too long (if that is what parallel for is doing)

The outermost loop cannot be parallel as each sample must be propagated in order.

Comment: The slowdown is likely from the nesting of the parallel operations, it is still after all AFAIK a "synchronous" operation at the point of calling (e.g. doScatteringForNodeRange won't run until the inner loop is done), which essentially means each outer loop is managing parallel state, spawning other parallel tasks and pausing. Ideally you want one loop to do everything, so: 1. See if you can expand the inner loop to be the main driver and 2. Avoid any shared state access.

Comment: By nesting of parallel operations do you mean the 2 parallel for's in this asnwer? Because as I have mentioned before I can not have the outer for as parallel and therefore did not implement it as such. All audio samples must be processed sequentially, only operations inside are candidates for parallelism.

But your point about swapping inner and outer loops is interesting, I will take a think about if this is possble!

Comment: I had a short think about swapping inner/outerloops. Within the logic of the algorithm this is not possible, each node relies on inputs from every other node at each timestep (or sample propagation), so they will be out of sync this way.